# Libreoffice calc problem under Kubuntu 22.04 Wayland

Tags: kubuntu, 22.04, wayland, plasma

I have recently upgraded to Kubuntu 22.04 and have tried Plasma on Wayland.  So far I have encountered a small problem when using the format painter in LibreOffice Calc.  I position the mouse over the area that I want to change format of and click but the area actually changed is one cell down.

If I use X rather than Wayland then Calc does what I expected.

Do I report a bug against Plasma, Wayland or LibreOffice?

Comment: I can not replicate this behavior on Kubuntu 22.04 running the flatpak version of Libreoffice under xwayland. Most probably the problem is with the wayland implementation of Libreoffice. I would report against Libreoffice.

Answer (score 0):

as the problem is specific to Libre Office you should report it - [this reference from the Document Foundation](https://blog.documentfoundation.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/How-to-Report-Bugs-in-LibreOffice.pdf) explains how.

The [Bugzilla site to report a bug is here](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=LibreOffice;bug_status=UNCONFIRMED;version=?)